# Enviar e-mail através do outlook

Tags: envio-de-email, delphi-7, outlook

Estou tentando enviar e-mail utilizando o outlook, através do Delphi7, utilizei essa [Documentação: Command-line switches](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Command-line-switches-for-Outlook-2010-ce2b9143-ceca-48ac-bffc-c3059a4c5919?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) para abrir o outlook com passagem de parametro da mensagem, conforma abaixo:

```
var
  para,assunto,mensagem : string;
begin
  para := 'email@email.com';
  assunto := '&subject='+'Contato secreto sobre o assunto';
  mensagem := '&body='+'Bom dia,
                        contato recebido com sucesso';

  WinExec(PChar('C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office16\outlook.exe '+'/c ipm.note /m '+para+assunto+mensagem);
end;
```

Mas quando envio, retorna a mensagem:

> Não é possível iniciar o Microsoft Outlook.
>   O argumento de linha de comando não é válido. Verifique as
>   opções usadas.

Comment: O que acontece se você copiar isso na caixa de texto no Dialog Executar do Windows e pressionar OK?

Comment: Mesmo erro, pois a mensagem vem direto do Outlook. Obrigado

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema é que o argumento passado como **/m** precisa estar entre aspas nas versões mais novas do outlook

```
WinExec(PChar('C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office16\outlook.exe '+'/c ipm.note /m "'+para + assunto + mensagem + '"');
```

Basicamente, o comando que deve ser executado é

> ```
> C:\> outlook.exe /c ipm.note /m "email@email.com&subject=assunto&body=corpo"
> ```

Comment: Muito obrigado, testei em um exemplo, com vários e-mails, e uma mensagem com varias linhas, e abriu o envio de mensagem do outlook.